# Element not filling parent in angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm building a mobile app which is intented for use on mobile devices. I started from the angular material-start [sample application](https://github.com/angular/material-start) and started modifying it to my needs. What I want now is to have one page with a full screen canvas.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to make the canvas fill the entire screen. The problem is shown here (red part is the canvas):

[image: example]

I have styling on the canvas like this:

```
#gameCanvas{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
}
```

but for some reason this won't work.

I have a CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPEZNP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`md-content` is a relative element. So to make the canvas use 100% of the space available, you can use this css instead :

```
#gameCanvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left:0;
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
}
```

<strike>Here's the forked [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPEZgG)</strike>

**UPDATE 2015-03-24**

The real `angular-material` way to do it is to use layout directives like this :

```
<md-content flex id="content" layout="column" layout-padding style="background-color: blue">
  <canvas layout-fill id="gameCanvas" flex></canvas>
</md-content>
```

You should also consider using `layout-padding`  directive instead of adding it yourself.

Here's the new [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwJqXp).